# Cross-references to a specfic page

Tags: cross-referencing, pdfpages

I've used `\includepdf[pages=-]{../<file>.pdf}` to include a external .pdf into my code, I would like to do a cross-reference to first page of this .pdf included.

Comment: What should this "cross reference" look like? Do you want to hyperlink (and jump) to it?

Comment: A simple number page (what jump, right) would be enough, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal document links is achieved using `\label` and `\ref`. However, these are typically tied to a *counter*. If you want a *general* internal document link, use a combination of `\hypertarget{<name>}{<stuff>}` and `\hyperlink{<name>}{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref}

\begin{document}

Here is a page:

\begin{center}
  \hypertarget{img:example-image}{%
    \includegraphics[page=1,width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{center}

Here is a link to the above image: \hyperlink{img:example-image}{Image}

\end{document}
```